# How can I plot a 3d antenna radiation pattern in python?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot a 3d antenna radiation pattern using python (or preferably in js if it's possible) but my code is not working.
Here is what my dataset looks like:

```
Theta [deg.]  Phi   [deg.]  Abs(RCS )[dB(m^2)]   Abs(Theta)[dB(m^2)]  Phase(Theta)[deg.]  Abs(Phi  )[dB(m^2)]  Phase(Phi  )[deg.]  Ax.Ratio[dB    ]    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 175.000           2.500           -4.083e+01          -4.117e+01             118.796          -5.208e+01             120.015           4.000e+01     
 177.500           2.500           -4.005e+01          -4.018e+01             118.327          -5.539e+01             117.213           4.000e+01     
 180.000           2.500           -4.054e+01          -4.055e+01             119.035          -6.585e+01             103.657           3.685e+01     
   0.000           5.000           -4.039e+01          -4.043e+01              52.496          -6.111e+01             247.581           3.244e+01     
   2.500           5.000           -4.028e+01          -4.039e+01              51.026          -5.616e+01             277.199           1.871e+01     
   5.000           5.000           -4.011e+01          -4.040e+01              52.497          -5.194e+01             295.813           1.265e+01     
   7.500           5.000           -4.016e+01          -4.043e+01              50.019          -5.247e+01             298.975           1.271e+01     
  10.000           5.000           -4.000e+01          -4.036e+01              50.000          -5.101e+01             306.994           1.091e+01     
  12.500           5.000           -4.026e+01          -4.064e+01              52.824          -5.102e+01             311.570           1.059e+01
```

Here are my functions for converting spherical to cartesian and vice-versa:

```py
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def spherical_to_cartesian(theta, phi, rcs):
    x = rcs * math.cos(phi) * math.sin(theta)
    y = rcs * math.sin(phi) * math.sin(theta)
    z = rcs * math.cos(theta)
    return x, y, z


def get_transformed_dataframe(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, sep="\s+", skiprows=2, header=None)
    df.columns = ['theta', 'phi', 'rcs', 'abs(theta)', 'phase(theta)', 'abs(phi)', 'phase(phi)', 'ax.ratio']
    result_df = df.apply(lambda x: spherical_to_cartesian(x.theta, x.phi, x.rcs), axis=1, result_type='expand')
    result_df.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']
    result = df.join(result_df)
    return result


df = get_transformed_dataframe('test.txt')
x, y, z = df.x, df.y, df.z
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
fig.update_layout(title='test')
fig.show()
```

This is my output, which shows nothing:
[image: Plotted output]

And this is the kind of output I'm trying to get:

[image: Desired output]

Any idea what is wrong with my code, and how can I get closer to my desired output?

Comment: two points 1. python uses radians by default. 2. `go.Surface()` z parameter is a 2D array not a 1D array.  Your code gives me a javascript error where this is really the issue